# Function not updating variables in Flutter

Tags: flutter, variables

```
void cellUpdate(cellNumber, players){
    if (moveValidity(cellNumber)==true){
      cellNumber= players;
      setState(() {
        cellNumber= players;
        print(cellNumber);
      });
    }
    else {
      print("This cell has already been filled!!");
    }
  }

  //CALLING FUNCTIONS REQUIRED FOR GAME INITIALIZATION


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[200],
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: const Text('3D Tic-Tac-Toe'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),

      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: GridView.count(
                childAspectRatio: 1,
                shrinkWrap: false,
                primary: false,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 95, vertical: 10),
                crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    color: Colors.teal[100],
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: (){
                        print("u1 got pressed");
                        cellupdate(u1,player1);

                      },
                      child: Image.asset(u1),
                    ),
                  ),
```

cellupdate () is not updating the value of u1 to player1. u1 is stuck at the initial state.

I tried to return the value of cellnumber in the function cellupdate(), but did not work.
I have now been thinking of hard coding these code in all lines but that is being very inefficient.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. And please use a linter (one should be turned on by default) and heed it's warnings.

Comment: is cellupdate in the State class of this widget, or a different widget?

Comment: You are declaring **cellUpdate** in camelCase but calling the function inside onPressed in small case **cellupdate** .Check once.

Comment: `cellUpdate` is assigning a value to the *parameter* `cellNumber`. Dart is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference. Function parameters are *local variables*,  assigning to them will not reassign the argument in the caller.

Comment: @jamesdlin that was really helpful. I was unaware of this.